# How to copy or return an object containing dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c++, object, memory-management, dynamic, copy-constructor

I have the following class:

```
class Matrix {
    int *A;
    int m, n;
...
};
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols){
    m = rows, n = cols;
    A = new int[m*n];
}
Matrix::~Matrix(){
    delete[] A;
}
```

I am trying to write a function which returns a Matrix object. In doing so, the default copy constructor is invoked, which means each the new returned object points to the same block of dynamically allocated memory as the one in the function. This causes the program to behave badly because this same memory gets deallocated when the object in the function goes out of scope.

How should I write my copy constructor? Is there a work around for this which doesn't require me to copy int array element-by-element?

Here's the function if it helps:

```
Matrix Matrix::submatrix(int r, int c){
    if (m <= 1 || n <= 1)
        return Matrix(0, 0);    //return null matrix 

    Matrix T(m-1, n-1);

    int ti = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        if (i == r) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (j == c) continue;

            T.A[ti] = this->valueAt(i, j);
            ti++;           
        }
    }
    return T;
}
```

Comment: See [rule of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: You may be looking for a move constructor and move assignment operator. You should also read about the [Return Value Optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which can remove the copy of the returned object in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the class `Matrix` you also have to add a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator in order to work with dynamically allocated memory in the right way.

Let's start with a copy constructor. The basic version might look like this:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other) {
    A = new int[other.m * other.n];
    std::copy(A, A + other.m * other.n, other.A);
}
```

You just allocate a memory for `A` and then copy the contents.

Now, copy assignment operator:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& other) {
    int* nA = new int[other.m * other.n];
    std::copy(nA, nA + other.m * other.n, other.A);

    delete[] A;
    A = nA;

    return *this;
}
```

It's a bit trickier. The code above allocates a memory for a new matrix, copies the contents into the newly allocated memory and releases the old memory then updating `A`. It uses a temporary pointer in order to deal with potentially throwing `new`.

Then, you might add a move constructor and a move assignment operator as well.

And, as it is mentioned, the *preferred* way is to use *STL* containers like `std::vector` which manage their memory on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Since you store the matrix efficiently in one large array, it is trivial to implement the copy constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix const& b) 
    : A(new int[b.m * b.n])
    , m(b.m), n(b.n)
{
    std::copy_n(b.A, b.m * b.n, A);
}
```

You may also like to store the array in `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`, so that it never leaks memory and protects you from accidentally copying it.

To implement the copy assignment I would suggest using `swap`:

```
void Matrix::swap(Matrix& b) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(A, b.A);
    swap(m, b.m);
    swap(n, b.n);
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix const& b) {
    Matrix(b).swap(*this); // Re-use the copy constructor.
    return *this;
}
```

You may also like to implement the move constructor and assignment in the similar fashion:

```
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix&& b)
    : A(b.A)
    , m(b.m), n(b.n)
{
    b.A = nullptr;
}

Matrix::Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& b) {
    Matrix(std::move(b)).swap(*this); // Re-use the move constructor.
    return *this;
}
```

---

Alternatively, store the array as `std::vector<int>`. This way the compiler generated copy constructor, move constructor, the assignments and the destructor do the right thing for you. This is also known as [rule-of-zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: Is there any reason to use unique_ptr over vector? If not I think vector is the best choice for me.

Comment: @DangerousTim `std::vector<>` is 3 times the size of `std::unique_ptr<>`. If you are concerned with CPU cache pressure and do not resize the vector using `std::unique_ptr<>` may result in faster code.